# IIS 7.5 running on Win7 Pro - access through a port other than 80 or 8080

Tags: asp.net, windows, http, iis

I'm not sure I can adequately explain my dilemma, but here goes...

Our company has its own web server at xyz.com. I have a Win 7 Pro machine running a non-HTTP server program that communicates with an iPhone app used by our field crews. The path to this machine from outside the network is abc.xyz.com, and it's set for port 5000. The app, then, is programmed to exchange data (ASCII only) with the server at abc.xyz.com:5000. The server program is written in VB, and the system works very well like that.

What I would like to do now is to add IIS to this same machine and open it on port 5001, so I can run asp.net pages that will enhance the functionality of the app for our crews. The URL would be abc.xyz.com:5001, and they will access it through their phone browsers.

I have IIS 7.5 installed on the machine, and I have started it running with the "default web site," and I have the binding set for port 5001. So far I am able to access the IIS "Welcome" page only from the same machine. I can't get it to come up on any other machine either inside or outside the network.

In searching for clues for this problem, all I read indicates that it's pretty much a snap to get a web server running on your Windows 7 machine. But it hasn't been so much a snap for me. I've checked the sharing settings and the security settings, they seem to be ok, as best I can tell.

I am hoping that someone will help me identify some obscure setting somewhere that I am overlooking and get this going. But I also even wonder if this is something that can't be done, i.e. because there's another server program using the same path running on port 5000.

By the way, I am not the network administrator. I try to avoid getting him involved because he's difficult to work with. I am hoping that this is just between me and my server.

Thanks for any insight anyone can give me.

Comment: This belongs on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You mention that you can access the website from the machine itself on port 5001, but you can't access the site from another computer within the same network - this suggests to me that the Windows 7 built-in firewall is blocking the request - as it's a non-standard IIS port.

You should configure the firewall to allow incoming requests on port 5001. Open a command prompt (as administrator) and run the following:

`netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name='IIS Website on Port 5001' dir=in protocol=TCP localport=5001 action=allow profile=any`

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention: port 5001 has been the port that my development software uses (production uses 5000), and it DOES go through from my development iPhone app to the development server. In other words, port 5001 functions properly when the VB development server software is running; it's when I try to configure that port to act as an IIS server (with the development server turned off to prevent port conflict) that it doesn't work. So does that mean the firewall is letting it through? Or is this 'netsh' command string specific to IIS? Thanks again. I hope I am making sense.

Comment: `netsh advfirewall firewall` isn't specific to IIS, it's specific to the windows firewall. Try temporarily disabling the firewall altogether to see if that solves your problem

Comment: Tom, thanks for your help. I managed to find the answer, which I have posted above.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [elsewhere on StackOverflow](https://serverfault.com/questions/38222/iis-7-5-windows-7-http-error-401-3-unauthorized). I needed to add IUSR to the list of authorized users. So far I have tested it on my iPhone browser using 3G and it came through. Seems likely that it will work from anywhere, but I'm not yet ready to declare total success.